# How can I send Shift cursor down to another program using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a problem here and have been stuck for weeks. I want to control another program remotely. The whole thing works great except for one thing. I can push buttons and write text in fields. I have a problem with a ListBox, I want to send a shift cursor down to mark more than one record here. I've tried everything possible here but it just doesn't work. I have already selected the LPARAM and the WPaman using MS Spy ++. I press Shift and curso down and log it using Spy ++. When I do all of this from my program, only one cursor down arrives there.
I use this code.

```
PostMessage (wndChild, WM_Keydown, VK_Shift, $ 002A0001);
PostMessage (wndChild, WM_Keydown, VK_DOWN, $ 01500001);
PostMessage (wndChild, WM_Keyup, VK_DOWN, $ C1500001);
PostMessage (wndChild, WM_Keyup, VK_SHIFT, $ C02A0001);
```

I already thought it was because of the program. For this reason, I quickly created a program in Delphi that only has a ListBox. It doesn't work there either.
Has anyone done this before and can tell me how it can make it work.
Thank you once.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)

Comment: "*I want to control another program remotely*" - that is what UI Automation APIs are meant for. Have you tried them yet?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PostMessage to simulate keyboard input.
Use the [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) call instead.

Comment: `SendInput` has very limited applicability. Outside of virtual keyboard implementations there's virtually no use for this API. The OP is trying to automate another application. The solution to that problem is [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).